# Cannot find the declaration of element 'DailySalesReportRQ'

Tags: sabre

I am trying to send a daily sales report request given my pseudo code and date but I am having an error. below is my request:

```html
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema">
 <SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <eb:MessageHeader SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" eb:version="1.0">
   <eb:From>
    <eb:PartyId>Client</eb:PartyId>
   </eb:From>
   <eb:To>
    <eb:PartyId>SWS</eb:PartyId>
   </eb:To>
   <eb:CPAId></eb:CPAId>
   <eb:ConversationId>{{convID}}</eb:ConversationId>
   <eb:Service>DailySalesReportService</eb:Service>
   <eb:Action>DailySalesReportLLSRQ</eb:Action>
  </eb:MessageHeader>
  <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
   <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">MY_TOKEN</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
  </wsse:Security>
 </SOAP-ENV:Header>
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
 <DailySalesReportRQ Version="2.0.0">
 <SalesReport PseudoCityCode="U16D" StartDate="2018-10-01"/>
 </DailySalesReportRQ>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Below is the response from the API:

```html
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap-env:Header>
      <eb:MessageHeader eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
         <eb:From>
            <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">SWS</eb:PartyId>
         </eb:From>
         <eb:To>
            <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">Client</eb:PartyId>
         </eb:To>
         <eb:CPAId>PCC</eb:CPAId>
         <eb:ConversationId>{{convID}}</eb:ConversationId>
         <eb:Service>DailySalesReportService</eb:Service>
         <eb:Action>DailySalesReportLLSRS</eb:Action>
         <eb:MessageData>
            <eb:MessageId>4721046418618811393</eb:MessageId>
            <eb:Timestamp>2018-11-05T11:37:41</eb:Timestamp>
         </eb:MessageData>
      </eb:MessageHeader>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
         <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">MY_TOKEN</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soap-env:Header>
   <soap-env:Body>
      <soap-env:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap-env:Client.Validation</faultcode>
         <faultstring>ERR.SWS.CLIENT.VALIDATION_FAILED</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01">
               <stl:Error timeStamp="2018-11-05T05:37:41-06:00" type="Validation">
                  <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                     <stl:Message>cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'DailySalesReportRQ'.</stl:Message>
                     <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.CLIENT.VALIDATION_FAILED</stl:ShortText>
                  </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
               </stl:Error>
            </stl:ApplicationResults>
         </detail>
      </soap-env:Fault>
   </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

What is wrong with my code? I tried to remove the version of DailySalesReportRQ but then a new error appeared: org.jibx.runtime.JiBXException: No unmarshaller for element "DailySalesReportRQ"

Comment: Why don't you use the WSDL and XSD to create a proxy? BTW you forgot to specify *any* of the Sabre namespaces. Notice how the `stl:ApplicationResults` defines the `stl` namespace with : `xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01"`.

Comment: A proxy would handle the SOAP headers, namespaces, validate values, parse responses etc. If you intend to hand-code parsing and generating Sabre requests you'll have to handle all namespaces, the ebXML exchange etc. You'll have to validate your XML strings against Sabre's XSDs anyway to ensure they are valid.

Comment: can i have a sample code for the proxy? im doing it in java.

Comment: There are dozens of SOAP libraries

Comment: Sabre also has [a Github repo](https://github.com/SabreDevStudio/SACS-Java) full of Java client samples